# Link from Post to Another Post Via Clicking on Words within Original Post

Tags: posts, pages, links

On WordPress (—-.wordpress.com), how can you write a post for example, but then within a post, create a link to another page on your website if someone clicks on a highlighted word? For example, if someone writes about pie and then uses the word cake in the post, can the person make it so that if people click (highlighted) cake, it will bring them to another article about cake on the website? If so, how?

Comment: do you mean automatically ? or just a hyperlink you add yourself?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean manually

when in you post, select the word you want to link. 
Next click the link button on top in the sinkbar.

in there you can enter your own url or choose 'existing content' . Click this and you will get a list of your other posts and pages.

Here you select the linked post.

[image: link to existing content]

Answer (score 0):

On `wordpress.com` sites you can not upload custom plugins, I think there are total **34 plugins** available for blogs on `wordpress.com` sites. If you didn't find correct plugin to do your stuff, then probably you should [request for it](http://en.support.wordpress.com/plugins/#plugin-requests).